# Combining multiple same iterations for rendering multiple divs for same list

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to do one iteration on a list and render multiple different html elements. In my current implementation, I have to iterate over same list multiple times to render multiple elements:

```
<%@ tag body-content="empty" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    <h3>For large screen size</h3>
    <div id="tabs" class="list-group">
        <c:forEach var="myListItem" items="${myList}" varStatus="status">
            <a id="myListItemNo${status.index}"
                class="list-group-item ${status.first ? 'active' : 'inactive'}">${myListItem.data}</a>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <h3>For small screen size</h3>
    <div class="myListItem-custom">
        <select id="myListItemOptions" name="myListItemOptions" class="form-control">
            <c:forEach var="myListItem" items="${myList}" varStatus="status">
                <option value="myListItemNo${status.index}"
                    ${status.first ? 'selected' : ''}>${myListItem.data}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tab-content" class="tab-content">
    <c:forEach var="myListItem" items="${myList}" varStatus="status">
        <div class="tab-pane ${status.first ? 'active' : ''}" 
            id="myListItemNo${status.index}Content">
            <h3>${myListItem.dataDetail}</h3>
        </div>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

I cannot use multiple similar `<c:if>` or `<c:choose>` for checking first and last list elements because they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: How about using only 1 loop and appending all html in some variable in each iteration and then finally print that variable inside your html code ?